# Setting HTTP Proxy on AWS API Gateway via Cloudformation

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-api-gateway, azure-api-management

Thanks for the help in advance.

Currently using cloudformation templates to deploy a simple API to AWS as part of a POC for moving from Azure to AWS API management.

I have got everything working except i have not been able to figure out the YAML AWS extension for setting the HTTP proxy checkbox for the HTTP request.

Sample YAML below. I know this will not set that checkbox (as i have tested it and it worked minus that problem), but on this page

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions-integration.html

i cannot see a extension that sets this option? Has AWS not done this yet

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Resources:
  PlayersAPI:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
    Properties:
      Name: RAH API
      Description: A demo API for testing
      Body:
        swagger: '2.0'
        info:
          title: test api
          description: test api
          version: 1.0.1
          contact:
            name: SH
            email: test@mailinator.com
        paths:
          "/heartbeat":
            get:
              description: Checks the API is working
              produces:
              - application/json
              responses:
                '200':
                  description: API Response information
              x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
                type: http
                responses:
                  default:
                    statusCode: '200'
                httpMethod: GET
                uri: https://api.example.com
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the motivation to moving from Azure API Management?  Maybe there something we can help with?

Comment: Did you see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions-any-method.html ?

Comment: EUREKA! (Thats aussie for bingo!) Thank you very much Tom.  On another note @DarrelMiller - The big reason is cost. You guys are not consumption based in that you have a high minimum monthly of $750 USD, and our AWS estimated cost is $150-200 a month based on our current data usage. I know you have the 22 a month option but 1) No SLA 2) Not meant for production. So price is really letting you down here. We like the API Management of Azure, but the $ talks when it comes to management.

Comment: @user2058234  Yes, I understand.  It has been a real thorn in our side too.

Comment: so @DarrelMiller thought you might like a update on this one. We stuck with Azure and its because we found a flaw in AWS where if the API timeout is longer than 30 seconds it discons. Our API is unique in that it needs extended processing time to complete its tasks which azure provides. Never change that please :)

Comment: @user2058234 I'm happy we were able meet your needs.  We actually allow you to configure a timeout value https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies#ForwardRequest

Comment: @user2058234 - One option you can do, but is recoding a bit, it have 2 API calls. First one starts the computations, second one polled every second or three to see if its done and get results.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
resources:
  Resources:
    ProxyResource:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
      Properties:
        ParentId:
          Fn::GetAtt:
            - ApiGatewayRestApi # our default Rest API logical ID
            - RootResourceId
        PathPart: "{proxy+}" # the endpoint in your API that is set as proxy
        RestApiId:
          Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
    ProxyMethod:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
      Properties:
        ResourceId:
          Ref: ProxyResource
        RestApiId:
          Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
        HttpMethod: GET # the method of your proxy. Is it GET or POST or ... ?
        MethodResponses:
          - StatusCode: 200
        Integration:
          IntegrationHttpMethod: GET
          Type: HTTP_PROXY
          Uri: http://bucket.mybucket.co.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/{proxy} # the URL you want to set a proxy to
          IntegrationResponses:
            - StatusCode: 200
        AuthorizationType: NONE
```